# what is the correct syntax to use getChatMember in a telegram bot with PHP - Core library?

Tags: php, bots, telegram

I hope my English is understandable.

I am making a bot for telegram in PHP. The bot is hosted on a web server (goDaddy)

The bot works, perform a test command: TestCommand.php And it works. Just return a message.

Then, do another command: OpenlistCommand.php and it works, but I have a problem with part of the code.

**command functionality:**
Create a .txt file to later host instagram usernames. **Works**!

The command should only be used in group chat, privately it returns a message saying "I can only open list in group".
**This all works.**

The problem is that, I need the command to only be activated by group administrators.

I use the getChatMember () to bring the Status (According to the telegram API, there should be the data I need) but I think I'm not doing it right, since the variable where I keep the data, is null.
Could you give me some guidance? Thank you

```
namespace Longman\TelegramBot\Commands\UserCommands;

use Longman\TelegramBot\Commands\UserCommand;
use Longman\TelegramBot\Request;

class OpenlistCommand extends UserCommand
{
   protected $name = 'OpenList';                      // Nombre de comando
   protected $description = 'Habilita la inscripcion de los usuarios a la lista'; // Descripcion del comando
   protected $usage = '/openlist';                    // Uso del comando
   protected $version = '1.0.0';                  // Version del comando

   //Funcion que ejecuta el Comando
   public function execute ()
   {

     $message = $this->getMessage();     // Captura el objeto mensaje
     $chatMember = $this->getChatMember(); // Deberia capturar el ChatMember

     $chat_id = $message->getChat()->getId();   // Captura el Id del chat
     $chatType = $message->getChat()->getType(); // tipo de chat private o group
     $status = $chatMember->getStatus(); // Deberia guardar el Status del usuario

     $data = [                                  // Setea los nuevos datos del mensaje
         'chat_id' => $chat_id,                 // Setea la id del chat para enviar el mensaje a:
         'text'    => '', // Setea el mensaje a enviar
         'chat_type' => $chatType, //private or group

     ];

     //Esta en chat privado?
     if ($chatType=='private')
     {
       $data ['text'] = 'Estamos en privado no puedo abrir lista';
        return Request::sendMessage($data);
     }
     else
     {
       if ($status =='administrator')
       {
       $data ['text'] = 'Lista abierta';
       $archivo = fopen("Lista.txt","a");
       return Request::sendMessage($data);
        }
        else {
          $data ['text'] = 'Tienes que ser administrador para abrir la lista';
          return Request::sendMessage($data);
        }
     }



   }


} //Fin clase
```

With this code the bot runs normal, but it does not identify that I am an administrator of the group. It returns the message of: "you have to be a group administrator"
I mean, the if condition is being false, and this is because $ status is null. (I already did tests returning the data in text and it doesn't return anything)

Some help? Please, I've been with this for two weeks and can't find any information anywhere.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I read your question while looking for a solution to the same problem.
I have found the way to do it, this code currently works

```
        // check if channel admin
        $member = Request::getChatMember([
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'chat_id' => $chat_id
        ]);

        if ($member->isOk()) {
            $member_data = $member->getResult();

            if($member_data->getStatus()) {
                $status = $member_data->getStatus();
            } else {
                $status = "";
            }
        } else {
            $status = '';
        }
        
        $isAdmin = false;

        if($status === 'creator' || $status === 'administrator') {

            $isAdmin = true;

        }
```

I see your question is from months ago, but I hope it helps you